# Syntax Error: unexpected token: '{' Where is the issue

Tags: javascript, screeps

I have been playing Screeps and whilst adding code to my main module, I got the above error. Unfortunately, Screeps doesn't tell you the location of an error like this, and I can't find anything. From my knowledge, the issue is that there is a bracket that is either missing or not supposed to be there. But as I said I can't see anything. Below is the code in question.

```
var roleHarvester = require('role.harvester');
var roleUpgrader = require('role.upgrader');
var roleBuilder = require('role.builder');
var roleAttaver = require('role.attacker');
var roleRepairer = require('role.repairer');

module.exports.loop = function () {
    var canspawnSmall = Game.spawns['Spawn1'].spawnCreep([WORK, CARRY, CARRY, MOVE, MOVE], 
    'Worker1', { dryRun: true });
    var canspawnBig = Game.spawns['Spawn1'].spawnCreep([WORK, WORK, CARRY, CARRY, MOVE, MOVE], 
    'Worker1', { dryRun: true });
    var harvesters = _.filter(Game.creeps, (creep) => creep.memory.role == 'harvester');
        console.log('Harvesters: ' + harvesters.length);
    var builders = _.filter(Game.creeps, (creep) => creep.memory.role == 'builder');
        console.log('Builders: ' + builders.length);
    var upgraders = _.filter(Game.creeps, (creep) => creep.memory.role == 'upgrader');
        console.log('Upgraders: ' + upgraders.length);
    var repairers = _.filter(Game.creeps, (creep) => creep.memory.role == 'repairer');
        console.log('Repairers: ' + repairers.length);
    var attackers = _.filter(Game.creeps, (creep) => creep.memory.role == 'attacker');
        console.log('Attackers: ' + attackers.length);

    if (harvesters.length < 2) {
        if (harvesters.length < 2 && canspawnBig == 0) {
            Game.spawns['Spawn1'].spawnCreep([WORK, WORK, CARRY, CARRY, MOVE, MOVE], 'Harvester' + Game.time, {memory: {role: 'harvester'} });
        } elif (harvesters.length < 2 && canspawnSmall == 0) {
            Game.spawns['Spawn1'].spawnCreep([WORK, CARRY, CARRY, MOVE, MOVE], 'Harvester' + Game.time, {memory: {role: 'harvester'} });
        }
    } elif (harvesters.length >= 2 && upgraders.length < 2) {
        if (upgraders.length < 2 && canspawnBig == 0 ) {
            Game.spawns['Spawn1'].spawnCreep([WORK, WORK, CARRY, CARRY, MOVE, MOVE], 'Upgrader' + Game.time, {memory: {role: 'upgrader'} });
        } elif (upgraders.length < 2 && canspawnSmall == 0 && canspawBig != 0) {
            Game.spawns['Spawn1'].spawnCreep([WORK, CARRY, CARRY, MOVE, MOVE], 'Upgrader' + Game.time, {memory: {role: 'upgrader'} });
        }
    } elif (harvesters.length >= 2 && upgraders.length >= 2 && builders.length < 2) {
        if (builders.length < 2 && canspawnBig == 0) {
            Game.spawns['Spawn1'].spawnCreep([WORK, WORK, CARRY, CARRY, MOVE, MOVE], 'Builder' + Game.time, {memory: {role: 'builder'} });
        } elif (builders.length < 2 && canspawnSmall == 0 && canspawnBig != 0) {
            Game.spawns['Spawn1'].spawnCreep([WORK, CARRY, CARRY, MOVE, MOVE], 'Builder' + Game.time, {memory: {role: 'builder'} });
        }
    } elif (harvesters.length >= 2 && upgraders.length >= 2 && builders.length >= 2 && repairers.length < 2) {
        if (repairers.length < 2 && canspawnBig == 0) {
            Game.spawns['Spawn1'].spawnCreep([WORK, WORK, CARRY, CARRY, MOVE, MOVE], 'Repairer' + Game.time, {memory: {role: 'repairer'} });
        } elif (repairers.length < 2 && canspawnSmall == 0 && canspawnBig != 0) {
            Game.spawns['Spawn1'].spawnCreep([WORK, CARRY, CARRY, MOVE, MOVE], 'Repairer' + Game.time, {memory: {role: 'repairer'} });
        }
    } else {
        console.log('All Set Chief')
    }
```

I believe the issue is somewhere above here but I am not sure.

```
   console.log('Can Big:' + canspawnBig)
        console.log('Can Small:' + canspawnSmall)
        const tower = Game.spawns['Spawn1'].room.find(FIND_MY_STRUCTURES, {
        filter: { structureType: STRUCTURE_TOWER }
        });
        if(tower.length > 0) {
            const closestDamagedStructure = tower.pos.findClosestByRange(FIND_STRUCTURES, {filter: (structure) => structure.hits < structure.hitsMax});
            if(closestDamagedStructure) {
                tower.repair(closestDamagedStructure);
            }
            
            const closestDamagedCreep = tower.pos.findClosestByRange(FIND_MY_CREEPS, {filter: (creep) => creep.hits < creep.hitsMax});
            if (closestDamagedCreep) {tower.heal(closestDamagedCreep);}
            
            const closestHostile = tower.pos.findClosestByRange(FIND_HOSTILE_CREEPS);
            if(closestHostile) {
                tower.attack(closestHostile);
            }
        }
    
        for(var name in Game.creeps) {
            var creep = Game.creeps[name];
            if(creep.memory.role == 'harvester') {
                roleHarvester.run(creep);
            }
            if(creep.memory.role == 'upgrader') {
                roleUpgrader.run(creep);
            }
            if(creep.memory.role == 'builder') {
                roleBuilder.run(creep);
            }
            if(creep.memory.role == 'attacker') {
                roleAttacker.run(creep);
            }
            if(creep.memory.role == 'repairer') {
                roleRepairer.run(creep);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think both code samples you posted are lacking a closing curly brackets ` } ` at the very end. Also in the first sample you are using `elif` which should be `else if`

Answer (score 0):

Because `elif` do not apply to Javascript. You need to change `elif` to `else if` in addition you don't have the close bracket for `module.exports.loop = function () {` adding this the code compiles

```
var roleHarvester = require('role.harvester');
var roleUpgrader = require('role.upgrader');
var roleBuilder = require('role.builder');
var roleAttaver = require('role.attacker');
var roleRepairer = require('role.repairer');

module.exports.loop = function () {
    var canspawnSmall = Game.spawns['Spawn1'].spawnCreep([WORK, CARRY, CARRY, MOVE, MOVE],
        'Worker1', { dryRun: true });
    var canspawnBig = Game.spawns['Spawn1'].spawnCreep([WORK, WORK, CARRY, CARRY, MOVE, MOVE],
        'Worker1', { dryRun: true });
    var harvesters = _.filter(Game.creeps, (creep) => creep.memory.role == 'harvester');
    console.log('Harvesters: ' + harvesters.length);
    var builders = _.filter(Game.creeps, (creep) => creep.memory.role == 'builder');
    console.log('Builders: ' + builders.length);
    var upgraders = _.filter(Game.creeps, (creep) => creep.memory.role == 'upgrader');
    console.log('Upgraders: ' + upgraders.length);
    var repairers = _.filter(Game.creeps, (creep) => creep.memory.role == 'repairer');
    console.log('Repairers: ' + repairers.length);
    var attackers = _.filter(Game.creeps, (creep) => creep.memory.role == 'attacker');
    console.log('Attackers: ' + attackers.length);

    if (harvesters.length < 2) {
        if (harvesters.length < 2 && canspawnBig == 0) {
            Game.spawns['Spawn1'].spawnCreep([WORK, WORK, CARRY, CARRY, MOVE, MOVE], 'Harvester' + Game.time, { memory: { role: 'harvester' } });
        } else if(harvesters.length < 2 && canspawnSmall == 0) {
            Game.spawns['Spawn1'].spawnCreep([WORK, CARRY, CARRY, MOVE, MOVE], 'Harvester' + Game.time, { memory: { role: 'harvester' } });
        }
    } else if(harvesters.length >= 2 && upgraders.length < 2) {
        if (upgraders.length < 2 && canspawnBig == 0) {
            Game.spawns['Spawn1'].spawnCreep([WORK, WORK, CARRY, CARRY, MOVE, MOVE], 'Upgrader' + Game.time, { memory: { role: 'upgrader' } });
        } else if(upgraders.length < 2 && canspawnSmall == 0 && canspawBig != 0) {
            Game.spawns['Spawn1'].spawnCreep([WORK, CARRY, CARRY, MOVE, MOVE], 'Upgrader' + Game.time, { memory: { role: 'upgrader' } });
        }
    } else if(harvesters.length >= 2 && upgraders.length >= 2 && builders.length < 2) {
        if (builders.length < 2 && canspawnBig == 0) {
            Game.spawns['Spawn1'].spawnCreep([WORK, WORK, CARRY, CARRY, MOVE, MOVE], 'Builder' + Game.time, { memory: { role: 'builder' } });
        } else if(builders.length < 2 && canspawnSmall == 0 && canspawnBig != 0) {
            Game.spawns['Spawn1'].spawnCreep([WORK, CARRY, CARRY, MOVE, MOVE], 'Builder' + Game.time, { memory: { role: 'builder' } });
        }
    } else if(harvesters.length >= 2 && upgraders.length >= 2 && builders.length >= 2 && repairers.length < 2) {
        if (repairers.length < 2 && canspawnBig == 0) {
            Game.spawns['Spawn1'].spawnCreep([WORK, WORK, CARRY, CARRY, MOVE, MOVE], 'Repairer' + Game.time, { memory: { role: 'repairer' } });
        } else if(repairers.length < 2 && canspawnSmall == 0 && canspawnBig != 0) {
            Game.spawns['Spawn1'].spawnCreep([WORK, CARRY, CARRY, MOVE, MOVE], 'Repairer' + Game.time, { memory: { role: 'repairer' } });
        }
    } 
    else {
        console.log('All Set Chief')
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but even after changing this (and only this) I still have an error. "missing ) in parenthetical". What does this mean and where is the issue.

Comment: somewhere in your code is expected to a close parenthesis. Check that all open parenthesis has a close parenthesis, for example if(var {   } needs a parenthesis like that if (var ) {  }

Comment: Thanks, but I have checked and they all do.

Comment: The error is because you don't have the close bracket `}` for  `module.exports.loop = function () {` adding this the code compiles correctly